# Validação de formulário usando o JQuery validate

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou aqui com um problema a validar o meu formulário, sempre que altero o País carrego de novo a página:

```
<select class="form-control" id="pais" name="pais" 
        onchange="document.getElementById('form_user').action='';this.form.submit();">
```

Faço isto para acrescentar novos campos se o país for Portugal.

O problema é que estou a usar o [validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) do JQuery e a validação deste e de outros campos desaparece, ao alterar o país, porque carrego de novo a página.

Como posso manter os campos de validação sempre a funcionar, a partir do momento em que clico **pelo menos um vez** no botão de *submit*?

Como eu faço a validação:

```
$('#form_user').validate({
        rules: {
            nome: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 50,
                required: true
            },
            //outros campos...
            pais: {
                valueNotEquals: "0"
            }
       }
       //mensagens, etc...
 });
```

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar ajax para pegar a lista de países?

Comment: Para que? A minha validação é se selecionou ou não um país.

Comment: Ah sim, entendi errado a questão. Pensei que recarregavas a página para obter a lista de estados e municípios, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que eu encontrei para resolver o problema foi verificar, no PHP, se foi feito um `POST`, se sim faço uma validação.

Assim fico com a garantia que cada vez que haja `POST` a validação é efetuada.

O meu *script*:

```
var validator = $('#form_user').validate({
    rules: {
        nome: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 50,
            required: true
        },
        //outros campos...
        pais: {
            valueNotEquals: "0"
        }
    }
    //mensagens, etc...
});
```

Se houver um `POST` é feita a validação do `form`:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
?>
    validator.form();
<?php 
}
?>
```

No caso do *click* no botão do `submit` também faz validação.

```
$( "#submit" ).click(function() 
{
    validator.form();
});
```